# Extract a string of data into separate cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to extract this string of images to be in separate columns in a Google spreadsheet:

```
http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/0812/85e6b1cb387b497875e956d7fc647d9bx.jpg|http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/1696/6dabcbb11e3e04f38083d6e18c2e0871x.jpg|http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/1635/2dd6f0254e7d7fd3b7170448fbf47491x.jpg|http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/1338/c0c9c3e0d7adad54b1bf57af7f86d539x.jpg|http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/1603/1cc5573b8f69ae77a10a2792b12f1c4dx.jpg|http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/0221/7913191ccdae92861e21a053441a804bx.jpg|http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/1407/4c18c403679d92c8a8a9b54b6b2c24c3x.jpg|http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/1235/33233205cd2aaf56e850727d3b620382x.jpg|http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/1180/20ade95871d6e5f800931ff0e4dd8e17x.jpg|http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/0477/826ed44616e07b8e52204b59dd98cd59x.jpg|http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/1436/38cf2bdb86a9de6c8b01e37a66c9dc61x.jpg|http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/1375/0a7013f826b1a96ada58b3d8f6890f4cx.jpg|http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/0462/a6ec2240a8bd8fd0bc8f37173c361eadx.jpg|http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/1729/4c93b3a4e58fdc073a94dd53bcdb6f10x.jpg|http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/1808/8446bd533763ccc2e917893941f144d6x.jpg|http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/1554/e1260c4b30212f6118c444161b001c88x.jpg|http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/0151/14ae78a4985b63f22cd1961cd931f154x.jpg|http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/1775/669d93f97eeac9de390da327bcf90df2x.jpg|http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/0169/c692f5505a4b8f08e3a04cc6390a5071x.jpg|http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/1577/792972cca053c8a4f46044d88f00b7a9x.jpg|http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/1225/d22a6578dfefb57d4a877326f198a41ex.jpg|http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/1805/9d8b0d2c943052f2e7078b08cc0d1842x.jpg
```

it has a delimiter of `|`

I was able to extract the first 2 images using these formulas which i put in 2 separate columns.

```
=LEFT(input!AD2, SEARCH("|",input!AD2,1)-1)
=MID(input!AD2, SEARCH("|",input!AD2) + 1, SEARCH("|",input!AD2,SEARCH("|",input!AD2)+1) - SEARCH("|",input!AD2) - 1)
```

I need to get at least 20 images from the list.

Comment: Are you looking for help with a script or with a formula? (questions on this site should be especific)

Answer (score 1):

Split the string and assemble for insertion into a column

```
function putInAColumn() {
  const data="http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/0812/85e6b1cb387b497875e956d7fc647d9bx.jpg|http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/1696/6dabcbb11e3e04f38083d6e18c2e0871x.jpg|http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/1635/2dd6f0254e7d7fd3b7170448fbf47491x.jpg|http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/1338/c0c9c3e0d7adad54b1bf57af7f86d539x.jpg|http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/1603/1cc5573b8f69ae77a10a2792b12f1c4dx.jpg|http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/0221/7913191ccdae92861e21a053441a804bx.jpg|http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/1407/4c18c403679d92c8a8a9b54b6b2c24c3x.jpg|http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/1235/33233205cd2aaf56e850727d3b620382x.jpg|http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/1180/20ade95871d6e5f800931ff0e4dd8e17x.jpg|http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/0477/826ed44616e07b8e52204b59dd98cd59x.jpg|http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/1436/38cf2bdb86a9de6c8b01e37a66c9dc61x.jpg|http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/1375/0a7013f826b1a96ada58b3d8f6890f4cx.jpg|http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/0462/a6ec2240a8bd8fd0bc8f37173c361eadx.jpg|http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/1729/4c93b3a4e58fdc073a94dd53bcdb6f10x.jpg|http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/1808/8446bd533763ccc2e917893941f144d6x.jpg|http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/1554/e1260c4b30212f6118c444161b001c88x.jpg|http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/0151/14ae78a4985b63f22cd1961cd931f154x.jpg|http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/1775/669d93f97eeac9de390da327bcf90df2x.jpg|http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/0169/c692f5505a4b8f08e3a04cc6390a5071x.jpg|http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/1577/792972cca053c8a4f46044d88f00b7a9x.jpg|http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/1225/d22a6578dfefb57d4a877326f198a41ex.jpg|http://pictures.dealer.com/l/lewisautogroup3/1805/9d8b0d2c943052f2e7078b08cc0d1842x.jpg"
  const dA=data.split('|');
  let cA=dA.map(function(e){return [e];});//adds the addition row arrays for insertion into a column
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  sh.getRange(1,1,cA.length,1).setValues(cA); 
}
```

[split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: but its coming from a document with many different string of images.  like each vehicle has a different string.

Comment: Well how about you write the script and get back with us if you have any problems.  Because it's hard to know what you need since your question is not that clear.....Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Tag Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)